# Cropped area rectangle show where previously cropped area like whats app

Tags: android, coordinates, crop

I'm developing Photoshop type app in which crop tools is using to crop image and i'm using default crop intent, when i cropped image i get bundle in which i got Rect(0,0-2,122) left,top,right,bottom but my point is when i cropped first time and again i cropped the cropper show its previously cropped area not default area and in crop intent.

```
CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", imageWidth);
CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", imageHeight);
CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 100);
CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", -100);
CropIntent.putExtra("spotlightX", 10);
CropIntent.putExtra("spotlightY", -10);
```

I pass l,t,r,b like this, i know this is wrong but i tried aspect x and aspect y are ratios but spot light is what, i don't know. can i place cropper at previously cropped area on same image.

Comment: improve code output

Comment: i got bundle in ActivityForResult in which i had image and its L,T,R,B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library from [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

and use below method two recover the ratio  on the image and call it where your image is to be cropped and remember when Activity is switched do not finish it.

```
 public void updateCurrentCropViewOptions() {
    CropImageViewOptions options = new CropImageViewOptions();
    options.scaleType = mCropImageView.getScaleType();
    options.cropShape = mCropImageView.getCropShape();
    options.guidelines = mCropImageView.getGuidelines();
    options.aspectRatio = mCropImageView.getAspectRatio();
    options.fixAspectRatio = mCropImageView.isFixAspectRatio();
    options.showCropOverlay = mCropImageView.isShowCropOverlay();
    options.showProgressBar = mCropImageView.isShowProgressBar();
    options.autoZoomEnabled = mCropImageView.isAutoZoomEnabled();
    options.maxZoomLevel = mCropImageView.getMaxZoom();
    options.flipHorizontally = mCropImageView.isFlippedHorizontally();
    options.flipVertically = mCropImageView.isFlippedVertically();
}
```